# Getting select option text based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu.  Given a given value, I would like to return the text.  For instance, 0 would return “zero”, 1 would return “one”, etc.  Note that I do not care which option is currently selected nor do I want to auto-select the menu, but just want to use the select menu as a primitive database.  Can this be done easily with JavaScript or jQuery without iterating over each option?

```
<select>
<option value="0">zero</option>
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
<option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

Thanks

Comment: Use the "selected:" selector (http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ckaufman/aDU5E/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using the `select` as a database *(requiring an expensive operation for simple lookups)*, create a data set from it once, then use that...

```
var vals = $('select option').map(function(i, el) { return el.text; })
                             .toArray();
alert(vals[2]); // "two"
```

---

Or if the `option` values aren't sequential `0` based indices, then use an object...

```
var vals = {};

$('select option').each(function(i, el) { vals[el.value] = el.text });

alert(vals[2]); // "two"
```

Comment: I was also planning on a similar approach.  Maybe the first time the data is needed, create the variable.

Comment: +1. Though I  don't think iterating 10 or even 100 options is expensive operation in our days. It just don't worth the time. Am I right?

Comment: @gdoron: You're right. I was thinking more of the DOM selection being an unnecessarily expensive way to store and fetch values.

Answer (score 3):

```
var value = '3';
alert($('select option[value=' + value + ']').text());
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6qrcN/).

Also you might want to give the select an id and update the selector because if you have multiple dropdown lists the selector won't work:

```
alert($('#id_of_the_select option[value=' + value + ']').text());
```

Comment: I don't know if the OP is interested in which value is currently selected. He wants to get the text given a value. Or maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: This does not return the text after selecting another option

Answer (score 1):

How else would you scan for a value without iterating over each option? There's no magic property that does it for you.

However, you can use this code:

```
(function() {
    var sels = document.getElementsByTagName('select'), l = sels.length, i,
        opts, m, j, o;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        o = {};
        opts = sels[i].options;
        m = opts.length;
        for( j=0; j<m; j++) o[opts[j].value] = opts[j].text;
        sels[i].map = o;
    }
})();
```

Put that just before `</body>`, and now you can find the map of any `<select>` on your page:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('mySelect');
alert(sel['0']);
```

Comment: btw, this is hundreds of times more efficient than any jQuery solution, just so you know ;)

Comment: Yea, bet it is way more efficient.  Probably keep with a jQuery solution for now, and later change everything after prototyping and going to production use.

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute-equals selector:

```
var valToSearchFor = 0;
    textFromOption = $('select option[value="' + valToSearchFor + '"]').text();
```

This will still iterate over every `option` to test for the presence of the value you're looking for, but it will do so 'behind the scenes' so that you don't have to.

There's the possibility of using `querySelectorAll()` (albeit with more or less the same notation as the above jQuery):

```
var valToSearchFor = 0;
    textFromOption = document.querySelectorAll('option[value="' + valToSearchFor + '"]').innerHTML;
```

This, of course, requires that the browser implements `querySelectorAll()`, and not all do (IE particularly).

References:

- [attribute-equals `[attribute="value"]` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll).

Comment: In your demo you set the value of an element to `4` and then try to retrieve the text of an element whose value is equal to `3`. Which doesn't exist. If you amend your demo to find an element with a value that exists, [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Meewa/2/).

Comment: No worries, I'm just somewhat embarrassed it took me so long to realise... =D

Answer (score 0):

Use the `selected:` Selector. Example given right on the page.

http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

```
 $("select").change(function () {
      var str = "";
      $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).text() + " ";
          });
      $("div").text(str);
    })
    .trigger('change');
```

Replace the "div" with the event you are trying to trigger

http://jsfiddle.net/ckaufman/aDU5E/1/

Comment: I believe this is used to just get the selected option.

Comment: Updated the example with your Option menu so you can see it in action. http://jsfiddle.net/ckaufman/aDU5E/1/